# Sets related combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

How many subsets of the set {1, 2, 3, 4, . . . , 30} have the property that the
sum of the elements of the subset is greater than 232?

I really have no idea how to move ahead with this problem.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: What is the sum of all the elements in the set?

Comment: The sum is 15x31= 465

Comment: Hint;  $465=232+233$.

Comment: $232$ looks very closely related to $465$.  Do you see how?  Might you come up with a conjecture about the number of subsets whose sum is *less* than or equal to $232$ and how this relates to the number of subsets whose sum is *more* than $232$?  Can you prove this conjecture?

Comment: Note:  They would not have expected you to be able to solve this question so easily if it were talking about the number of subsets whose sum was greater than some other number like $280$.

Comment: So sum of elements in each subset, can either be less than 232, equal to 232 or more than 232. Every subset which has sum less than 232 has a counterpart whose sum is more than 232 and which has to be present in the set of sets whose sum is greater than 232. This is a bijection right? So,

Comment: ((2^30)-number of subsets whose sum of elements is 232)/2

Comment: Close.  Consider more carefully the case of if a subset had sum exactly equal to $232$.  What is it's complement's sum.  Recall $232 = 465-233$

Comment: So the above mentioned logic does not give a bijection

Comment: No wait actually it does,

Comment: Is the answer 2^29?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gathering comments and including the punchline:

Note that $1+2+3+\dots+30 = \dfrac{30\times 31}{2}=15\times 31 = 465$ is the sum of all elements in the set.

Recognize that $232+233=465$ so $232$ is the floor of half of the total sum of all elements.

We conjecture that the subsets whose sum is strictly more than $232$ is in bijection with the subsets whose sum is less than *or equal* to $232$.  Indeed, suppose you have a set whose sum is $s> 232$.  Then it's complement has sum $465-s<233$ and vice versa.

As such, we learn that the number of subsets with sum more than $232$ is exactly equal to the number of subsets with sum less than or equal to $232$ and so the number of subsets whose sum is more than $232$ is exactly half of the total number of subsets, $2^{30}$

The final answer then:

$$2^{29}$$